# Проверка на наличие поля

Tags: javascript

Мне приходят данные и как проверить если есть в них поле friendslist или нет?

```
if(data какое условие писать сюда?){
}
else{
}
```

Вот пример

```
{
    "friendslist": 1,
    "id": "847",
    "msg": "OK"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if(имя вашего ключа(поля) in инспектируемый объект){ } else{ }

```
var obj = {"a": false}
    obj.b = undefined

if("a" in obj){
 console.log("ключ 'a' присутствует в объекте obj, его расширение " +obj["a"])
}
else{}

if("b" in obj){
 console.log("ключ 'b' присутствует в объекте obj и его расширение " +obj["b"])
}
else{}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var test = {
    "friendslist": 1,
    "id": "847",
    "msg": "OK"
};

if(test.friendslist) {  // if(test['friendslist']) {
    console.log('есть поле');
} else{
    console.log('нет поля');
}

// Если значение поля может содержать ноль
if(typeof test.friendslist !== 'undefined') { 
    console.log('есть поле');
} else{
    console.log('нет поля');
}
```

Comment: `"friendslist": 0, // Ooops`

Comment: @Grundy так, и?

Comment: `"friendslist": undefined, // Ooops`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский без палева исправил :)

Comment: @DogeDev просто не надо встревать в середине написания ответа  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯